# How to show app icon in custom lock screen when creating new notification from GCM in Android

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I am showing a notification when a GCM is received. The notification is created as follows:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notifications_black_24dp_1x)
            .setContentTitle(senderName)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setVibrate(new long[]{0, 500}) //{ delay, vibrate, sleep, vibrate, sleep } in millisecond
            .setPriority(2)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Everything seems to work fine. But if I get the GCM when my phone is locked, I can't see anything in the lockscreen notification circle. I want to make it look like in the below image (the gmail icon inside the circle). I am testing on a Moto X Style device (Android 6).

[image: Moto X Style lock screen]

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you already need this, but i came across the same problem, while searching i found this topic:
[Notifications in Moto Display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36890362/notifications-in-moto-display)

Marcin stated:

> Thanks, I ready this many times but problem was in vector drawable instead of bitmap in small icon. Moto Display cant use vector. I hope this will help somebody :)