# Notifications in Moto Display

Tags: android, notifications, lockscreen

I created a notification and it works but not display in Moto Display when locked.
I changed Priority, Category etc with no effects.
I want this notification like messages or missed cals:
[moto display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwUWS.png)

This runs as a service:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.emblem2)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_help_red))
                    .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorFirst))
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(location)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setShowWhen(true)
                    .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_ALARM)
                    .setLights(Color.YELLOW, 200, 200)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

   notificationBuilder.setVibrate((sharedPreferences.getBoolean("notifications_new_message_vibrate", false) ? new long[]{0, 300, 200, 300} : new long[]{}));
            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                    (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(requestCode, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: may be your apps are locked, although check your your  setting**sound & notification** find **when device is locked**.

Comment: i checked and i have it enabled, all aplications are displayed except my, even signed app, maybe it must be istalled from Google Play?

Comment: for detailed documentation go [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) may be you missed something.

Comment: Thanks, I ready this many times but problem was in vector drawable instead of bitmap in small icon. Moto Display cant use vector. I hope this will help somebody :)

Comment: ok i got in my moto, goto **moto** than **display** and change the setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Marcin, Moto Display **doesn't work with vector drawable in notification small icon**. I had the same problem and changing the small icon resolved the issue.

It's sad that such a nice feature as Moto Display doesn't have a documentation pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

```
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
    // Show controls on lock screen even when user hides sensitive content.
    .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_player)
    // Add media control buttons that invoke intents in your media service
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_prev, "Previous", prevPendingIntent) // #0
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_pause, "Pause", pausePendingIntent)  // #1
    .addAction(R.drawable.ic_next, "Next", nextPendingIntent)     // #2
    // Apply the media style template
    .setStyle(new Notification.MediaStyle()
    .setShowActionsInCompactView(1 /* #1: pause button */)
    .setMediaSession(mMediaSession.getSessionToken())
    .setContentTitle("Wonderful music")
    .setContentText("My Awesome Band")
    .setLargeIcon(albumArtBitmap)
    .build();
```

That worked in my Moto Z, maybe only work in Media mode.